# Usage of Adal.js with Custom Login Page

Tags: javascript, ajax, single-sign-on, single-page-application, adal.js

We have a custom login page that contains user_email_address field and fetching tenant and application details through AJAX once user clicks on Login page. 
After that setting the `AuthenticationContext` using Adal.js and redirecting to Microsoft Login Page for input the password.

Since `AuthenticationContext` not available during the start of the application,  Page redirection & token renewal not happening every time.

How can we achieve SSO in this scenario?

Any help greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I understand it is not possible to have it in your application to take credential inputs to pass on to Azure. Instead it allows limited customization on the login page for your organization branding.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/customize-branding